# How do you run a SQL select query in real time using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm currently building a commenting system in PHP for a school project, but I stumbled upon a problem. I want the user to be able to post a comment which is inserted without refreshing. I got this working. I also want the post to load all comments, including the one that was just posted by the user.

I've no idea how to do the latter, so that's why I'm asking here for advice/tips/examples.

This is the code I'm using right now to load all comments for the current post. It's working, but I'd like to replace this somehow with an AJAX code that does the same, but in 'real time'.

```
include('dbconnect.php');
$stmt = $db->prepare("
SELECT c.comments_id, c.time, c.comment, c.date, c.posts_id, c.users_id, users.users_id, users.name, users.surname, users.profilepicture 
FROM `comments` as c k
INNER JOIN users ON c.users_id = users.users_id 
WHERE c.posts_id = ".$row["posts_id"]);
$stmt->execute();
$amtResults = $stmt->rowCount();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo '<div class="row">
            <div class="column column-1">
                 <img style="padding-left:5px;padding-top:5px; height: 30px; width: 30px;" class ="commentuppic" src="/uploads/'.$row["profilepicture"].'" alt="Profile picture">
            </div>
            <div class="column column-9">
               <p id="replytext">   
                   <a href="profilefriend.php?user_id='.$row["users_id"].'">'.$row["name"].' '.$row["surname"].'</a>:<br>
                '.$row["comment"].'
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="column column-1">
                <form method="post">
                    <button type="submit" style="width: auto;" name="delete_comment" ><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></button>
                    <input type="hidden" name="comments_id" value="'.$row["comments_id"].'" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>';
}
```

If it's needed, here's the code I used for inserting the comment into the database:

```
       $("form[name='submit_comment']").submit(function (e) {
            //do whatever you want to do when submitting comment
            var comment = $('#comment').val();
            var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'insertmessage.php',
                //async: true,
                //cache: false,
                data: {comment:comment, post_id:post_id},
                type: 'POST',           
            });

        return false;
        });
```

and the insertmessage.php:

```
if($_POST["comment"]){
    include('dbconnect.php');
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // prepare sql and bind parameters
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO comments ( date, time, comment, posts_id, users_id ) VALUES ( :date, :time, :comment, :posts_id, :users_id )');
    $date = date("Y/m/d");
    $time = date("h:i:sa");
    $stmt->bindValue(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':time', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':comment', $_POST["comment"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':posts_id', $_POST['post_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindValue(':users_id', $_SESSION['users_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $db= null;
    header('Location: profile.php');
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: I would highly recommend @David his solution, as it works well and is easy to implement!

Comment: You should have a REST api with the `addComment` endpoint, then perform a request to add the comment. This request will then return a list of all comments in the post, which you can use to populate the comment section

Comment: Realtime data usually works well with a NoSQL database

Comment: What's your exact question about this? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase it's an old question, and has been solved already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comment is successfully insert into the data, just add it to the page.  This would be done in a `success` callback in the `$.ajax()` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'insertmessage.php',
    data: {comment:comment, post_id:post_id},
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (response) {
        // here you would add it to the page
    }
});
```

(There's also an `error` callback to handle error responses, you may want to look into that as well so you can notify the user if something goes wrong.)

You already have the `comment` value, so unless there's additional information you need from the server then you can probably just ignore the `response` in the callback.  But if there *is* information you need from the server, that's where you'd get it.

(Note, however, that currently your server-side doesn't doesn't *write* anything to the response.  It returns a redirect, which AJAX requests basically ignore.  If you want to return any data, you'd have to write it to the response just like you would in any other PHP page (though preferably using `json_encode()` for AJAX responses) instead of the redirect.)

How you display the comment on the page is up to you, really.  That depends on the page's HTML and where you want to add the comment.  But since you're using jQuery it should be pretty easy.  For example, if you want to add the comment to a known element, you might add it like:

```
var existingComments = $('#someElement').text();
$('#someElement).text(existingComments + comment);
```

That's probably too simplified, but hopefully you get the idea.  Or you might wrap the comment in a new element and append it to something:

```
$('#someElement').append('<div>' + comment + '</div>');
```

There are countless possibilities, really.  But the main point is that you'd do this in the `success` callback in the AJAX call.  Basically, the order of operations would be:

1. Send the comment to the server
2. Insert into the database, return success
3. Add the comment to the page

Comment: Hey David, thanks a lot for your reply. I choose to not use this approach as I need some variables from the database upon adding the new comment, which is (as far as I'm concerned) not doable this way.

Comment: @Sandertjuhh: It is doable.  All you have to do is return those values (preferably as a JSON object) from your PHP page to the client.  The other answer may get you past this one hurdle, which is great.  But you may want to look into how to make use of AJAX in order to not have to simply re-load the entire page every time you change anything.  (Which is essentially what AJAX is meant to avoid.)

Comment: I looked further into it, and the only probleem seems to be that I don't have access to the comment_id. If you look at my first post, you can see that I use a $row["comments_id"] in the foreach to give an ID to a delete button, so the comment can be deleted. If I would append a comment, it would also need this delete button with the ID of the comment. Do you have any idea how I would get around this, or a way to fix this?

Comment: @Sandertjuhh: In the PHP page, instead of redirecting the user (since AJAX ignores that anyway), echo the information you need to the response (just like any PHP page).  Something as simple as `echo $comment_id;` could do it (or whatever variable would hold that identifier, which you can get from the database as the last inserted ID if that's where it originates).  Then that response would be in the parameter of the AJAX `success` callback.

Comment: Oh that sounds pretty nice, one thing, how would I use the parameter of the AJAX success callback? In my php file where I insert the data I now also echo the latest comments_id from the database which I need. I tried to look it up on the internet, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @Sandertjuhh: Anything emitted to the response should be in the first parameter to the `success` callback function.  In your browser's debugging tools, take a look at the network response from the AJAX request.  Additionally, place a break-point in the `success` callback function and examine the value of `response` (or whatever you choose to name the first parameter to that function).

Comment: Great, it's working now. The 'response' parameter literally holds the value now. You're a legend.

Comment: @Sandertjuhh: As a learning exercise, I recommend that you build an object of some kind in PHP and then `echo json_encode($yourObject);` and then look at what's in the `response` parameter.  You can send all sorts of structured data back to the client, and it'll be far more efficient than requesting the whole page again.

Answer (score 0):

for the reloading part use "success" function.
Doc : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

And use .load() to reload the content without refreshing the page. 
Doc : http://api.jquery.com/load/

your code will look like this :

```
$("form[name='submit_comment']").submit(function (e) {
            //do whatever you want to do when submitting comment
            var comment = $('#comment').val();
            var post_id = $('#post_id').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'insertmessage.php',
                //async: true,
                //cache: false,
                data: {comment:comment, post_id:post_id},
                type: 'POST',
                success : function(code_html, statut){ 
                    $('#your_comment_container').load(document.URL +  ' #your_comment_container');
                }
            });

        return false;
        });
```

Comment: Seems kind of unnecessary to load the entire page when all of the data needed is already client-side.  This will load *all* comments (all but one of which are already displayed) as well as *the rest of the page* and just filter down to the new one (which is already in the `comment` variable).

Comment: it didn't load all the content, just the container you need. I prefere knowing what actually in my DB than just emulating it. But that's just my point of view, he need an answer we gave him several, he choose what he want.

Comment: how then do you listen when a new comment have been typed

Comment: I like the idea of just 'refreshing' a div, but there's one problem I encountered. The comments are loaded from a SQL query, so after executing the query I load the comments in a foreach loop. Each time a comment is being looped over, I echo the html and the corresponding query data.So for example I would have 2 posts, with each having a certain amount of comments. If I would comment on the first post, AJAX would trigger that container with comments to load again. How would I select in the success function of AJAX which container to load as they all have the same class? @T.J